# how to replace a string into an anchor tag in php

Tags: php, regex

I am having of problem on how to replace a text into an anchor tag in which text has 
also text similar in href property of a tag.

The text should display below:

```
//input
  $string = "text1 text2 text23 text24";
  $tofind   = "text2";
//output
  <a href="welcome_to_text2.php">text2</a>
```

I used the code below but with wrong output:

```
<?php
  $fulltext = "text1 text2 text23 text24";
  $tofind   = "text2";
  $string   = explode(" " , $str); 
  foreach($string as $value){ 
     $href     = "welcome_to_{$tofing}.php";
     $fulltext = preg_replace('/('.preg_quote($tofind, '/').')/i', 
               "<a href=\"{$href}\">"."\\1"."</a>", $fulltext );
  }
   echo $fulltext ;  
   //it outputs  <a href="welcome_to_<a href=""">text2</a>
?>
```

text23 and text24 is also replaced since text2 occurs on both string. I just only want to replace the text2 alone since it matched.
Does anybody know? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below:

```
$fulltext = "text1 text2 text23 text24";
$tofind   = "text2";
$array   = explode(" " , $fulltext);
$fileKey = array_search($tofind, $array);
// if giving file does not exist use 'text1' as default.
$fileName = isset($array[$fileKey]) ? $array[$fileKey] : 'text1';

echo sprintf('<a href="welcome_to_%s.php">%s</a>', $fileName, $fileName);
```

Or if you want build links for all elements in array:

```
$fulltext = "text1 text2 text23 text24";
$tofind   = "text2";
$array   = explode(" " , $fulltext);
$text = '';
foreach ($array as $value) {
  $text .= sprintf('<a href="welcome_to_%s.php">%s</a><br />', $value, $value);
}
echo $text;
```

Hope it helps.